# How to invoke an iMacro from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

I have an iMacro '**Test.iim**' and I want to play or call this **iMacro** from a javascript that is attached into a button click event in my webpage.
 Please Help with some sample code.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is this.

```
iimPlay("Test.iim")
```

When calling a macro inside a Macros folder put "" around the macro and it will play it. Also you can add timer for that macro like this.

```
iimPlay("Test.iim",60)
```

This means the macro has maximum 60 seconds to complete.

When playing the macro which is declared as variable inside the .js file then you do it like this

```
var test;

test ="CODE:";
test +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES "+"\n";
test +="URL GOTO=www.google.com "+"\n";


iimPlay(test,60)
```

And that is all.

Answer (score 1):

simple example code would be:

```
iimPlay(Test.iim);
```

here you can find additional information about it: http://wiki.imacros.net/iimPlay

Comment: I tried the above code but its not working. When i debugged in IE, its showing that iimPlay is not defined.

Comment: use it with imacros firefox add-on

Comment: In order to call a macro from the application, do we need the Paid Version of iMacro?

Comment: basically yes, but you can call simple iim scripts with imacros://run/?m=you-script-name.iim you'll have to make sure your firefox is open before calling the script.

Comment: @Bestmacros it gives me an error as <b>ReferenceError: iimPlay is not defined</b> when I am trying to run it from a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an [imacros java script converter](https://xs-sol.com/imacros-java-script-converter/) where you copy paste your whole script, and recieve the final code as a java script.